# Can the inherited class see the change of the value on the parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have two classes. **class A** has a public variable **X**, which is used by both classes,
**class A** changes the value of **X** every 3 seconds, while **class B** prints the new value of **X**. But the **class B** sees the initial value **10** only. I need **class B** to see the change of the variable **X** in **Class A**.

```
import threading
import time
class A():
    X = 10
    def __init__(self):
       self.first() 
    def first(self):
      while True:
        self.X = self.X + 3
        print("A",self.X)
        time.sleep(3)
    
class B(A):
   def __init__(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target= self.second, args=())
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start() 
   def second(self):
        while True:
            print(self.X)
            time.sleep(3)
example1 = B()
example2 = A()
```

Comment: ``A.X`` is never modified – the code only touches ``self.X``, where ``self`` are *instances* of ``A``. If the code would modify ``A.X``, then ``B`` and its instances would see the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not setting the class variable `X`.

```
self.X = self.X + 3
```

On the first iteration `self.X` is reading the class variable since there is no instance variable `X`.

However it assigns the instance variable and from that point on, `self.X` within `A` is an instance variable and any changes made are not reflected in `A.X`.

You can fix this by making the first argument of the method (`self`) refer to the class and not the instance with the `@classmethod` decorator.

```
    @classmethod
    def first(cls):
        while True:
            cls.X = cls.X + 3
            print("A",cls.X)
            time.sleep(3)
```

Full code:

```
import threading
import time
class A():
    X = 10
    def __init__(self):
        self.first()
        
    @classmethod
    def first(cls):
        while True:
            cls.X = cls.X + 3
            print("A",cls.X)
            time.sleep(3)
    
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target= self.second, args=())
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start() 
    
    def second(self):
        while True:
            print(self.X)
            time.sleep(3)
example1 = B()
example2 = A()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access its parent's X, `A`'s x, by either using: `A.x` or `super().x`

Comment: This won't change the problem that `A.X` is not being changed.

Comment: You can change `A.x` directly then? with `A.x += 3` or 'super().x += 3'?

Comment: `super().X += 3` would not work since the assignment is in the base class. Doing it directly with `A.X` would work. As a personal choice I would use a `classmethod` since the instance doesn't appear to be used in that method.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work the way you think it should work. The objects A() and B() are not the same as classes A and B. The objects are separated instances. When you change x using object A(), object B() doesn't know anything about the change that happened. And it couldn't.
If you need it to work the way you want, you should add A() into b's initializer. And then call the variable of A() object.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, A_instance):
        self.a = A_instance

    def working(self):
        x = self.a.x
```